# apache nifi: hive closes connection and workflows stop working

Tags: apache-nifi

I noticed some workflows stop working because the connection pool looses connection to hive, if I stop and then restart the connection pool anything work. How can I avoid this problem working only on hive? Does anybody faced this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, DBCP currently assumes the connections are valid, so it can return such a connection the next time the processor runs, causing the error you are seeing.

I think HiveConnectionPool would benefit from the same fix in [NIFI-2381](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2381), and perhaps other DBCP settings to ensure only valid connections are returned/borrowed. I have written [NIFI-2927](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2927) to cover this.

Unfortunately I believe the only workaround at present is to restart NiFi.